# org.jsoup.HttpStatusException error

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am using jsoup in an android app to grub a url, I got this error and searched a lot but can't find an answer, can you give me some advice? Thanks! I test it in Android 2.1 emulator, the code is as bellow:

```
Document doc;
String firstHash = "";
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(mURL)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0")
        .timeout(10000).followRedirects(true).execute().parse();
        firstHash = doc.body().text();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

stack trace is as follow:

```
10-20 08:42:37.586: W/System.err(223): org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=-1, URL=http://www.shooter.cn/files/file3.php?hash=duei7chy7gj59fjew73hdwh213f&fileid=244789
10-20 08:42:37.606: W/System.err(223):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
10-20 08:42:37.606: W/System.err(223):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
10-20 08:42:37.606: W/System.err(223):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ignoreHttpErrors(true), will surely solve your problem

```
Document doc3 = null;
    try {
        doc3 = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```